# Linebreak in Python3 Lists

Tags: python-3.x

How to linebreak in Python3 lists? \n is not working in this particular case.

```
**areas = ["hallway", 11.25, "kitchen", 18.0, "living room", 20.0, "bedroom", 10.75, "bathroom", 9.50]

downstairs = areas[:6]

upstairs = areas[6:]

print(downstairs \n upstairs)**
```

it returns:

```
**File "<stdin>", line 9
print(downstairs \n upstairs)
                                ^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character**

PS: This is my first question ever here :)

Comment: Have you read any tutorials on string concatenation in python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Brace. Brace. Brace. It isn't uncommon for folks to get flamed for posting a syntax error question, though this is a good quality post otherwise. I hope you enjoy using the site. Cheers!

Comment: @ialarmedalien : Im just thru three hours of a long tutorial, but I guess that doesnt matter. I wasnt askiing about concatenation, I just wanted a linebreak; if that is something that is related, I wouldn't know. But anyways, very helpful your comment. Thanks for your warm welcome.

Comment: @Elletlar ... same.

Comment: What output are you trying to get? The `\n` is a string, which you need to concatenate with the two variables, `upstairs` and `downstairs`... hence asking you about string concatenation.